# Example to call subprocess with cmd.exe

Tags: python

I want/try to run cmd.exe with 2 commands: "ver", then "exit",

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
def do_process(command, text):
    pro = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    out, err = pro.communicate(text.encode())
    return out

do_process(['cmd.exe'], 'ver\nexit\n')
```

it cannot return the output, seems cmd.exe is not ended. What is ok way.

Comment: In windows, `Popen` goes through `cmd.exe` when `shell=True`. You can boil this down to `return subprocess.call('ver')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made err inside my function, I need to `decode` result (I use cp866 on my OS):

```
def do_process(command, text):
    enc = 'cp866'
    p = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate(text.encode())
    return out.decode(enc)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a very reliable method calling `cmd.exe` and I'm almost sure you won't be able to communicate with it properly.

In case you want to retrieve system version, you might use this:

### Called on my machine

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.platform()
'Linux-3.17.4-1-ARCH-x86_64-with-glibc2.2.5'
```

### Called on some Windows machine

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.platform()
'Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1'
```